# ExtJS 4.2 RowExpander issue (second row is indented)

Tags: extjs, extjs4, extjs4.1, extjs-mvc

I'm trying to add to my grid the `RowExpander` plugin.

Seems everything was going great with just one row, but when adding a second row the following rows are indented.

I have created a Sencha Fiddle: https://fiddle.sencha.com/#fiddle/87d

I'm doing it exactly as Sencha Examples, maybe because I have a datetime column first I get that issue.

Any help is welcome.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can't specify your component `widget.dailytimesummary` and then only add a plugin to it when you instantiate it or it won't get initialized as desired.

Instead, your plugin should be a part of the initial definition of your widget:

See your corrected jsfiddle here: https://fiddle.sencha.com/#fiddle/87m

```
...
enableColumnHide: false,
enableColumnMove: false,
// this needs to be configured with the initial component
plugins: [{
    ptype: 'rowexpander',
    rowBodyTpl: ['{Date}']
}],
selModel: {
    enableKeyNav: false
},
...
```

Comment: Amazing... thanks a lot!! Actually there is an Ajax RowExpander that works for 4.1.1 and I just ported to 4.2.1 and works amazing. Where can I share that?